# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:validate/validate.dart'

Tags: flutter

[image]

I tried running flutter packages get. Restarted IntelliJ community but still:

[image]

Need solution in this missing imports for future different packages that will come.

Comment: After a `flutter packages get`, IntelliJ does not immediately take account of the new packages in the dart files, and suggests another `packages get`. If you don't have this option, have a look at [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30845).

Comment: Look in the `.packages` file and confirm first that the package is present - that will confirm that `pub get` worked. BTW your question is better suited to the 'chat' style of gitter. Consider asking it there.

Comment: `validate:file:///C:/Workspace/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/validate-1.7.0/lib/` entry present in `.packages` . I updated to flutter 1.0 beta. @RichardHeap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open Quick Action Search Tool using **cntrl+Shift+A on windows**;

search for "**restart dart analysis server**" press it to execute, this will make dart to analyze project again.